# Segmentation Fault cuando redirijo entrada, pero funciona cuando es por consola

Tags: c, gdb

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WLEN      32    /* word length */
#define LOGWLEN   50016 /* log word length -- round(LOG2(WLEN) */
#define SMAX      50016 /* maximum string length -- multiple of WLEN */
#define BITMAX    128   /* maximum bit string length -- round(SMAX/WLEN) */
#define ALPHASIZE 26    /* alphabet size */

typedef unsigned int WORD;
typedef short unsigned int INDEX;   /* i: alpha[i] == char */

int nwords;             /* no. of words for bits */
WORD bit1[BITMAX];
WORD bit2[BITMAX];
WORD a_strings[ALPHASIZE][BITMAX];
WORD *pb1, *pb2, *t1;

WORD bitmask[LOGWLEN] =
        {0x55555555, 0x33333333, 0x0f0f0f0f, 0x00ff00ff, 0x0000ffff};

void bitops(last, cur, index)
WORD *last, *cur;
INDEX index;
{
    register WORD x, y;
    register int j;
    register WORD *a_s;
    register WORD top_borrow, bottombit;

    a_s = &a_strings[index][0];
    bottombit = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < nwords; j++) {
        y = *(last++);
        x =  y | *(a_s++);
        top_borrow = (y >> (WLEN - 1)) & 0x1;
        y = ((y << 1) | bottombit);
        if (x < y)
            top_borrow = 1;
        *(cur++) = x & ((x - y) ^ x);
        bottombit = top_borrow;
    }
    return;
}

void alphastrings(s, len)
INDEX *s;
int len;
{
    register INDEX *p;
    register int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ALPHASIZE; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < nwords; j++)
            a_strings[i][j] = 0;
    p =  s;
    j = len;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
        a_strings[*(p++)][i/WLEN] |=  1 << (i % WLEN);

    return;
}

int bitcount(wp)
WORD *wp;
{
    register WORD w, count;
    register int j, rshift, i;

    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++) {
        w = *(wp++);
        rshift = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < LOGWLEN; j++) {
            w = (w & bitmask[j]) + ((w & ~bitmask[j]) >> rshift);
            rshift <<= 1;
        }
        count += w;
    }
    return (count);
}


int bitlcs(a, lena, b, lenb)
INDEX *a;
int lena;
INDEX *b;
int lenb;
{
    register int i;
    register INDEX *pbstring;
    register int j, k;

    nwords = (lena + WLEN - 1) / WLEN;

    alphastrings(a, lena);

    pb1 = &bit1[0];
    for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++)
        *pb1++ = 0;     /*** bit1[i] = 0; ***/
    pb1 = &bit1[0]; pb2 = &bit2[0];
    pbstring = b;

    for (i = 1; i <= lenb; i++) {
        bitops(pb1, pb2, *(pbstring++));
        t1 = pb1; pb1 = pb2; pb2 = t1;
    }
    return (bitcount(pb1));
}

int leer(INDEX * s) {
    int c, index, i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        s[i++] = (int) c - 97; 
    }
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    INDEX stringa[SMAX];// = {1, 1, 1};
    INDEX stringb[SMAX];// = {1, 2, 1};
    int lenA, lenB;
    lenA = leer(stringa);
    lenB = leer(stringb);
    printf("%d\n", bitlcs(stringa, lenA, stringb, lenB));
    return 0;
}
```

Estoy testeándolo con 50000 letras "a" y 50000 letras "e" como entrada, para eso armé un archivo con dichas letras. El problema se dá en que cuando compilo con:

```
gcc -O2 miPrograma.c -o miPrograma.exe
```

Y lo ejecuto con `./miPrograma.exe < strings.txt`

Arroja `Segmentation Fault`, aunque si lo ejecuto simplemente `./miPrograma.exe` y copio y pego ambos strings funciona correctamente.

Probé, además, que al debuguearlo con

```
gcc -O2 miPrograma.exe -g
gdb ./a.out
run < strings.txt
```

También funciona perfectamente, por lo que no puedo ver donde se encuentra el problema. No se qué hacer, si alguien pudiera darme una mano se lo agradecería.

**UPDATE**

He notado que cuando el número de caracteres decrementa no hay problema con las redirecciones, por lo que claramente es un problema a la hora de almacenar los 50000 de cada letra.

Comment: ¿Has probado a utilizar `-O0` en lugar de `-O2`? He probado en Ubuntu 14.10 con la siguiente linea de comandos: `gcc -o test -O0 -ggdb3 -test.c` y la salida que me retorna es `0`. Como recomendación, si estás utilizando gcc, verifica si puedes utilizar el estándar C11 o C99.

Comment: ¡ Por Dios ! ¿ Ese código de donde ha salido ? `register`, declaración de argumentos al estilo `K & R`, ... Hacía **decadas** que no veia algo así :-O

Comment: Es un algoritmo de LCS con bits sacado de http://users.monash.edu/~lloyd/tildeStrings/Alignment/86.IPL.html

Comment: Hola @NaCl, gracias por responder; como dices, así funciona, pero los flags que requiero son los que utilizo. No hay manera de debuguear esto con GCC, de manera que se ejecute exactamente igual que cuando lo llamo después de la compilación normal?

Comment: Ahí postee la solución! Gracias a ambos por tomarse la molestia de responder! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahí solucioné el problema.

En cuanto al `SIGSEGV` estaba en presencia de un Heisenbug tal como se explica en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628521/segfault-only-when-not-using-debugger). Desactivando la randomización de memoria en el debugger se solucionó:

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
```

En cuanto al algoritmo, tenia un problema de seteo de la macro `BITMAX` (cuyo valor se establece a partir del redondeo de la división SMAX/WLEN) la cual había quedado con el valor 128 y me había olvidado de cambiarlo al correspondiente (1563) al actualizar los valores de SMAX y WLEN.